# C# WebRequest to a URL that is configured for Windows Authentication

Tags: exchangewebservices, restsharp, webrequest, ntlm

I am trying to get user photos out of Microsoft Exchange using the GetUserPhoto REST request documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj190905%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

My problem is no matter what I do the connection gets closed automatically and it can't authenticate using NTLM. Microsoft even provides code but when you run this in a IIS web application even if it is using an application pool running as a domain user, it never can authenticate.

This is my current code that isn't working:

```
request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create($"https://{Settings.ExchangeServer}/ews/exchange.asmx/s/GetUserPhoto?email={primarySmtpAddress}&size=HR240x240") as System.Net.HttpWebRequest;

                        request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
                        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                        resp = request.GetResponse() as System.Net.HttpWebResponse;
```

Now I can put this in a console application and run it and then it works. But in IIS it just won't work at all. I've even tried RestSharp with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was it wasn't trying to connect with TLS 1.2. Once it clicked in my head, the error message was saying the connection closed and not actually returning a 401. I user ServiceManager to set it to TLS1.2 and then it started working.

Glen Scales help point me in the right direction though to troubleshoot it further.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a delegation issue eg the credentials your impersonating can only be used to access resources local to the IIS server they are being impersonated on. For you to access Exchange you need to have delegation configured correctly see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emeamsgdev/2012/11/05/ews-from-a-web-application-using-windows-authentication-and-impersonation/

Comment: The thing I see is that is still using ASP.NET impersonation and Windows Authentication which will impersonate the user logging into the application.

I'm more wanting to make a request to the Exchange EWS URL using the credentials that the application is running under (the credentials on the application pool).

Comment: But it will be the same delegation issue when App pool credentials are used and the same solution should work.

Comment: Ah, so I can keep anonymous authentication because I use forms auth but enabling Windows Auth and impersonation may allow the credentials to pass through? I will give that a try

Comment: Basically my application pool is integrated mode and I want to impersonate the application identity when making a call to EWS. I followed that article other than the application pool being classic mode and didn't have any luck so far. Still testing though.

Comment: I would check the steps in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chiranth/2014/04/17/setting-up-kerberos-authentication-for-a-website-in-iis/ and make check the useAppPoolCredentials value. You can also run through the Kerberos troubleshooting https://blogs.iis.net/bretb/How-to-Use-DelegConfig

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Glen. I read the article and one thing he specifically mentions is anonymous authentication must be disabled because it takes precedence over Windows Authentication. Maybe I should try impersonating the user in code somehow instead of trying to make it use the application pool